# Is there a way to change a nickname in an event in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like to change peoples names to their original name + 1 when they send a message.

I've got all the code for the message detection, but not for the changing names.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
      if message.author == bot.user: return
      await client.change_nickname(message.author, "...a")
```

I expect a name to change to . . .a when they send a message but it does nothing.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing an error message?  If not, do you have any error handling that could be keeping an error from being logged or printed?

Comment: Is far I see from the docs the `change_nickname` represents guild-specific permissions. In order to change nick of user you have to [call edit on a member and pass the nick parameter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Member.edit)

Comment: Yes, I do get an error message,  
    File "nickbot.py", line 17, in on_message
        await client.change_nickname(message.author, " ...a") 
    AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'change_nickname'
I'm not sure at all what's happening
@PatrickHaugh

Comment: Sounds like you're using the rewrite without realizing it.  The new version was officially released a few days ago, so you may have updated by accident.  Either migrate your code to discord.py 1.0+ or pin your version to 0.16

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in comment:

> As far I see from the docs the `change_nickname` represents
>   guild-specific permissions. In order to change nick of user you have
>   to call [edit on a member and pass the nick parameter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Member.edit).

Something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
      if message.author == bot.user: return
      await message.author.edit(nick="some new nick")
```

For your specific need of nick in the form of `original name + 1` you can use something like this:

```
import re 

# Extracts digits that are at the end of string user_name
#
# @param user_name a string to extract digits from
# @return extracted digits as integer or -1 if error
def extract_number_suffix(user_name):
    # Using regex to find all digits at the end of the user_name
    # source https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search
    # regex entry: https://regex101.com/r/WQkzhw/1
    extracted= re.search(r"[0-9]+$", user_name)
    try:
        return int(extracted[0])
    except:
        return -1


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
      if message.author == bot.user: return
      previous_name = message.author.name
      number = extract_number_suffix(previous_name)
      if number == -1:
          # If number is -1 that means that the function extract_number_suffix
          # failed to extract a number because user has no number at the end of
          # it's name. So we just set the name to name1
          await message.author.edit(nick="{}1".format(previous_name))
      else:
          # Remove the current digit suffix
          clean_name = previous_name.replace(str(number ), "")
          # Increment current number and change nick
          new_number = number + 1
          await message.author.edit(nick="{0}{1}".format(clean_name , new_number ))
```

You can also use `message.author.display_name` which:

> Returns the user’s display name.
>
> For regular users this is just their username, but if they have a
>   guild specific nickname then that is returned instead.
>   [source](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Member.display_name)

Answer (score 0):

`Discord.py-rewrite` and `Discord.py` are different branches of the API. The rewrite branch is the one that's the most up to date with the Discord app and its official API

Inside `rewrite` you'd change it like this

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    await msg.author.edit(nick=f'{msg.author.name}1')
```

Inside the `async(discord.py)` branch, it'd be done like this

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    await client.change_nickname(msg.author,'{msg.author.name}1')
```

`async` attributes for client can be found [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/client.py) and the `rewrite` documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html)